# Intercept the Share click on Gallery

Tags: android

Is it possible to listen to the click of the Share button in Android's Gallery app? After I capture that click, I want to start my Activity without presenting the list of apps the user can share with.

I know I can listen to Intent.ACTION_SEND and display my app in the share menu but I am not looking for that implementation.

I'd appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't intercept it unless you modify Android itself and deploy the new custom rom on the phone.. and honestly I don't think you should be able to intercept it either. That would give your app an unfair advantage and would not follow the android design that all apps are equal (including system supplied apps like Gmail or so).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying as well as explaining.